# Android: How to return a string from Cursor adapter

Tags: android, string, cursor

My aim for my app is to show a list of modules which is pulled from a SQLite database. If a user clicks a particular module a new activity begins which gives further information stored within the database related to that one particular module.

What I was hoping to do was get the row id and send this in an intent however, I'm unsure how to get the row id from a cursor adapter into an onClickListItem? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Cursor Adapter

```
public class TestCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater viewInflater;
    public TestCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        viewInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) 
    {
        TextView text_modulecode = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.labelModuleCode);
        TextView text_modulename = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.labelModuleName);

        text_modulecode.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(database.KEY_MODULECODE)));
        text_modulename.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(database.KEY_MODULENAME)));

        String moduleId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(database.KEY_ROWID));
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = viewInflater.inflate(R.layout.listcourses, parent, false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

From main activity

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
      {
          super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,ViewCourse.class);

            //--->             <--
            intent.putExtra(TEST,moduleId);
            startActivity(intent);
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the arguments of onListItemClick

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
```

ID is there.. This is automatically populated with the row ID by the cursor adapter..

Comment: Oh right. But does that mean if  row_id 19 was deleted for example, row_id 19 would not appear in the onListItemClick?

Comment: If your listview still has row id 19 after you've deleted it.. you should get id 19 in the on item click. However, your adapter / listview should be reacting to deletes and removing from the list

Answer (score 0):

```
intent.putExtra(TEST, String.valueOf(id));
```